# Where does JMeter keep test/application logs?

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to monitor the logs from my tests (or applications if you will). For example, I might have a log line in the code like this:

```
logger.info( "dummy log" );
```

However, when I run JMeter like this:

```
jmeter -n -t foobar.jmx
```

I have no idea where to look for that dummy log. So, where does JMeter keep the logs from the tests? Better yet, how can I configure it?

Thank you very much.

**update**
I forgot to mention that the test logs were not found in the default log file `jmeter.log`. Is that true that the test logs should appear in the `jmeter.log` unless there are some settings disabling the output of the test logs?

**update 2**
I have pasted the jmeter.properties here: http://pastebin.com/6paTqRrK

Below are relevant code snippets.

```
package foo.bar;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class DummyTest {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( DummyTest.class.getName() );

    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("dummy message");
        logger.info("dummy log");
        assertTrue( true );
    }
}
```

Gradle build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.1'

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    runtime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.13'
    runtime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.0.13'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

// bundle everything into a fat jar
jar {
    from {
        configurations.testRuntime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        } + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output

    }
    archiveName = 'junit_sampler.jar'
}

task updateJar( type: Copy, dependsOn: jar ) {
    from './junit_sampler.jar'
    into "${System.properties['user.home']}/opt/apache-jmeter-2.11/lib/junit"
}
```

**foobar.jmx**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.6" jmeter="2.11 r1554548">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Check Logging" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">3</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1399656770000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1399656770000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <JUnitSampler guiclass="JUnitTestSamplerGui" testclass="JUnitSampler" testname="JUnit Request" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="junitSampler.classname">foo.bar.DummyTest</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.constructorstring"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.method">test</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.pkg.filter"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.success">Test successful</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.success.code">1000</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.failure">Test failed</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.failure.code">0001</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.error">An unexpected error occured</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.error.code">9999</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.exec.setup">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.append.error">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="junitsampler.append.exception">false</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="junitsampler.junit4">true</boolProp>
        </JUnitSampler>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Somehow, the "dummy log" message just doesn't show up in the jmeter.log.

Answer (score 5):

By default all logging goes to `jmeter.log` file which is usually located in /bin folder of your JMeter installation. However the location may vary basing on how you launch JMeter and what would be it's working directory. See [FileServer](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html) API for more details.

If you want logging output from a custom class, extension or plugin it might be supressed by configuration. Try "telling" JMeter the desired log level for your class via property.

See `user.properties` file in /bin folder of your JMeter installation for sample logging levels configuration and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for how to change them.

However I'm pretty sure that if you initialize your `logger` as follows:

```
import org.apache.jorphan.logging.LoggingManager;
...
...
private static final Logger logger = LoggingManager.getLoggerForClass(); 
...
logger.info("sonething");
```

You will see that "something" line in the log.

Hope this helps.

Comment: -@Dmitri: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, somehow it is not working on my end. I added more details to the question. Please take a look. I have also pasted my jmeter.properties to pastebin. The link is in the question. Additionally, I tried `org.apache.jorphan.logging.LoggingManager`, but gradle cannot resolve a dependency for jorphan, so this solution won't work for me as I want to keep gradle.

Comment: You need to additionally configure `sl4j` logging to append output to jmeter.log file (or any other file). http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html

Answer (score 2):

For JMeter 2.13 you need to edit bin/log4j.conf where general log4j settings can be placed. For example, the bin/root.log file will be recorded as specified below:

```
###############################  IMPORTANT NOTE  ##############################
# JMeter does not use log4j as logging system
# This configuration will only be used by libraries that do use log4j
# or your custom code if it uses it

log4j.appender.Root_Appender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Root_Appender.File=root.log
log4j.appender.Root_Appender.Append=true
log4j.appender.Root_Appender.MaxBackupIndex=0
log4j.appender.Root_Appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Root_Appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d{MM/dd, hh:mm:ss} %-20.30c %m%n

log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG,Root_Appender
```

Answer (score 0):

The log file name is defined in the **jmeter.properties** file (or using the -j option, see below). It defaults to **jmeter.log , and will be found in the directory from which JMeter was launched**.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging

Comment: Hi, I didn't see the test logs in jmeter.log. Please see my update.

Comment: I just tested it with **jmeter-2.9** in my machine. I run the jmeter in command line mode by changing the directory to **\apache-jmeter-2.9\apache-jmeter-2.9\bin** and enter *jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l logjtl.jtl*.

Comment: Found jmeter.log in bin folder is updated and contains the log.

Comment: If you change any settings in jmeter, try with a fresh jmeter by extracting the jmeter zip.

Comment: -@Nidheesh: Thanks for following up. Really appreciate it. I added more details to my question. I believe all you said, but somehow it is not working on my end.

Answer (score 0):

you have to allow your class package in log4j property of jmeter (under bin folder ex: apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/log4j.xml)

[sample log4j.xml com.tgs.jmeter with debug level added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MeI2.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed JMeter from the ubuntu store you will find **jmeter.log** at your user's home location.
to see logs `tail -f ~/jmeter.log`